# Executar aplicação Java em um Servidor

Tags: java, servidor

Eu tenho uma aplicação feita em java que fica atualizando o meu banco de dados. Entretanto, eu não quero rodá-la 24/7 no computador da minha casa por razões óbvias (internet pode falhar, energia pode cair...). Então, eu preciso colocar o meu programa em um servidor... Eu não tenho ideia de como fazer isso, eu verifiquei alguns produtos da Amazon, mas não tenho certeza se meu programa serve. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Tenta comprar um servidor (VPS) e instala o Tomcat ou o Glassfish lá. Você também pode procurar outros provedores de cloud ou hospedagens java - Try to buy a server (VPS) and install Tomcat or Glassfish there. You might also look for other cloud providers or java hosting services.

Comment: Quais são os requisitos da sua aplicação? Qual é a estrutura dela? Qual é o banco de dados?

Comment: @nbro Porque a pergunta originalmente estava em inglês (olhe o histórico). Talvez o autor não saiba português.